# Apply sorting on specific template

Tags: solr, content-search

I'm using Sitecore 9.3, I have search API that fetches two types of templates, Product and Content Page, the search results are always a combination of these two types.

I apply boosting on Product template so that it's always on the top of search results.
We have sorting functionality to sort Products by its price.

The sort of course is applied on all the search results, so when sorting by price in ascending order, the Content Pages are shown on the top as it has 0 price.

I want to sort only the Products without affecting the Content Pages order.

This is just a sample from the used code, it can give you an overview:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchModel>();

using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName.ToLower()).CreateSearchContext())
{
    var searchPredicate = context.GetQueryable<SearchModel>().Where(predicate);
    
    searchPredicate = searchPredicate.SortBy(sortAscending);
    
     return searchPredicate.GetResults();
}


private  IQueryable<SearchModel> SortBy(this IQueryable<SearchModel> source, bool ascending)
{
    return ascending ? source.OrderBy(item => item.Price) : source.OrderByDescending(item => item.Price);
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `OrderBy().ThenBy() ` with first lambda `r => r.Template == Product` (or maybe `!= Product` )?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I tried it but didn't work, whatever written in the lambda expression, it will be applied on the results.

Comment: Maybe you call `ToList()` too early? or something similar?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I don't think so, I'm using IQueryable search predicate, so I'm building my predicate with all the input like sorting, then execute it at the end by calling GetResults()

Comment: It would help if you added your code example to your question

Comment: @RichardSeal  updated the question from the used code.

Comment: Might be better to form 2 lists: 1 with Products and the other with Content. Sort them separately and then merge them

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay
I agree with you, it just might affect the performance, but yes this is the only way as I can see.